# NSOperationQueue continues to run in the background even though it's not configured to do so

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

In the process of making my app be able to continue running `NSOperations` added to an `NSOperationQueue` after it has moved to the background, I discovered that this happens anyway, even though there's nothing that specifies that it should continue running in the background.

The following code will continue logging "Finished" after the app has moved to the background, it will continue to do so till all 50 tasks have been executed.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        sleep(3);
        NSLog(@"Finished %u", i);

        switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState) {
            case UIApplicationStateActive:
                NSLog(@"App is active");
                break;
            case UIApplicationStateInactive:
                NSLog(@"App is NOT active");
                break;
            case UIApplicationStateBackground:
                NSLog(@"App is in the background");
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
}
```

What am I missing here? I though that the execution would stop as soon as the app goes to the background, and I have to explicitly run background tasks if I need to do so.

Comment: Are you testing on a device or in the simulator? Are you running while connected to Xcode or not?

Comment: Yes, I was testing on the simulator. And I just realized that when running on the simulator, the app is allowed infinite background time without being terminated. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it is running under Xcode that gives you infinite background time; It will happen on a real device too if you are running under the debugger